# Linear programming problem with extra condition

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am working on a problem that might be represented as a linear programming problem.

I am just a bit stuck around one extra condition that is usually not part of a typical linear programming problem, but I think this could be represented in the conditions.

The real life problem is: on a marketplace there are different offers with different prices and amounts to sell some specific good. We need to find the optimal (cheapest) selection of offers to buy a specified amount of goods, but with the condition that one could only buy from a strictly limited number of offers. For example maximum 3 offers could be used to buy 26.5 metrics tons of salt, while minimizing the cost of the purchase. On the market of salt there are different offers. Some can deliver up to 2 tons, some up to 20, but for different prices. We need to choose some offers (maximum 3 in this case) to purchase 26.5 tons of salt for the minimal total price possible , while still buying only from 3 offers.

So the goal is to choose a S subset of offers from the available O set of offers. The maximum size of S is limited to L. Each offer has a defined price per unit and a defined amount of units available for sale. Both the price and the amount available for sale are non negative real numbers. The selected S subset should have the minimal total cost for the items in it and still have at least B amount of units offered in them. Of course we are only paying for the amount that we actually buy to purchase B amount. So only the cost of the amount that is needed to buy the total B amount should be considered in the total cost.

I understand that the LP problem's cost function should include the cost in some way. I am just not exactly sure how I could define the problem using the usual LP matrix and vector for the cost function.

I am also not completely sure if this issue really needs to be addressed as linear programming problem and I am also not sure if it is even possible. Is there a better approach to find an optimal selection (lowest total price), while still fulfilling the conditions? Eventually some dynamic programming based solution?

Could you please help me and tell if this problem could be represented as linear programming problem and if this is a good approach or you would rather recommend somenother approach to solve this problem?

Comment: (1) You need to be more precise in the offerings. Exactly 2 tons at price p, or up to 2 tons. It helps to write down the mathematical model: it forces you to be more precise. (2) Counting ("only from 3 offers") is typically done using binary variables. So, your model is no longer an LP but a MIP.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment before: you can model your prob as a MIP, some solvers offer even SOS which might be adequate for your case.(See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_ordered_set)

Answer (score 0):

The problem cannot be formalized as a Linear Programming problem.

For the formal description binary variables are needed, which describe if a given offer is chosen or not. These can be used to represent the requirement that only a limited number of orders might be used to

```
ci: the cost of one unit of offer i
xi: the amount to buy from offer i
yi: 1 if we buy from offer i
T: the total amount to be bought
L: the upper limit of the number of offers to buy from
Ai: the available amount in offer i


Objective: 
  min { ci xi }

Constraints:
  Σ(xi) = T
  Σ(yi) <= L
  Ai * yi - xi >= 0

Bounds:
  0 <= xi <= Ai
  0<= yi <=1

  yi are integer
```